Build failed in KMM project when trying to run IOSapp from Android studio to IOS simulator
This question have been asked here, but the solutions given only cover for old version of IDEs, I'm currently running on Android Studio Jelly fish, Xcode 15.3, IOS simulator 17.4, all plugins and dependencies are up to date, yet i still get the same error. I have exhausted all forms of solution and yet no result.
This error only comes up when deploying app to ios simulator, works fine on android emulator
The following build commands failed:
    PhaseScriptExecution Compile\ Kotlin\Framework/Users/xblack/KMPprojects/KMPdemo2/build/ios/iosApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iosApp.build/Script-F36B1CEB2AD83DDC00CB74D5.sh (in target 'iosApp' from project 'iosApp')

(1 failure)
warning: Run script build phase 'Compile Kotlin Framework' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'iosApp' from project 'iosApp')


To anyone still experiencing this check this answer, worked for me
